# Huawei turing wifi on slow

Tags: wi-fi, huawei-honor-6

I using huawei 3C. Everytime I turn on the Wi-Fi, it takes time to turn on...I've been waiting for more than an hour but still unable to connect.

[image]

Comment: Check if the MAC address is still present. Settings > About device > Status. Does the Bluetooth works?

Comment: @esQmo MAC address still present but bluetooth address unavailable

Comment: It appears unavailable because you haven't enabled it.

Comment: @esQmo the MAC address present but why cannot connect wifi ?

Comment: The Wifi seems not enabling at all. It is a common issue with this phone! People are having problems with wifi not connecting, try googling.